# POST http://127.0.0.1:5500/add 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Tags: javascript, node.js

Could you help me solve this error? It seems that I can not connect between server.js and app.js.

What I want to do is: display the result of the postData('/add', {answer:42}); and postData('/addMovie', {movie:'the matrix', score:5}); in the console.

Thank you for your help in advance.

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvo4P.png)

server.js

```
// Setup empty JS object to act as endpoint for all routes
projectData = {};

// Require Express to run server and routes
const express = require('express');//add

// Start up an instance of app
const app = express();//add

/* Dependencies */
const bodyParser = require('body-parser') //add
/* Middleware*/
//Here we are configuring express to use body-parser as middle-ware.
//we can connect the other packages we have installed on the command line to our app in our code with the .use() method
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Cors for cross origin allowance
const cors = require('cors');//add
app.use(cors());//add

// Initialize the main project folder
app.use(express.static('website'));

////////////////////creating a local server
const port = 5500;//add
// Setup Server
//////////////////////add
const server = app.listen(port, listening);
function listening(){
    // console.log(server);
    console.log(`running on localhost: ${port}`);
};

app.get('/all', function (req, res) {
    res.send(projectData)
})

// POST route
const data = []
app.post('/add', callBack);

function callBack(req,res){
    res.send('POST received');
    console.log(data)
}

const movieData = []
app.post('/addMovie', addMovie )

function addMovie (req, res){
    movieData.push(req.body)
    console.log(movieData);
}
```

app.js
[app.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7IRQ.png)

[Addition]
Thank you for your feedback!!
I changed the port in server.js, but nothing changed.
[port5500](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdhDf.png)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Try properly formatting the code in your question and only include minimal, reproducible example.

Comment: You are posting to the wrong server (probably to your frontend and not to your backend). Your backend is listening on port 8002, not 5500!

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! I changed the port NO, but nothing changed.

Comment: Update your code body in the question to reflect any changes you've made~

Comment: Yes, I already changed it. PORT NO is 5500 now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved.

```
// when using local server ( ≒ server.js in this case)
postData('/add', {answer:42});
postData('/addMovie', {movie:'the matrix', score:5});

// when using live server
postData('http://localhost:5500/add', {answer:42});
postData('http://localhost:5500/addMovie', {movie:'the matrix', score:5});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

You need to add an "allow" in the header field to support this or explicitly allow it in your webserver configuration

A lot of the time, this is set up in the configuration of your .htaccess or nginx.conf file (depending on the webserver). It will commonly be found in your RewriteRule section. You can look for a "R=405" flag there.

Comment: They don't appear to be using Apache HTTPD

Comment: I'm using javascript so I don't understand that.